# Why does this AWS Lambda function return JSON instead of HTML?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the following lambda function, with an API Gateway trigger point:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
resp = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    "body": "Hello, World!"
}

return resp
```

When I navigate to the API endpoint, I expected to only see the text "Hello, World!". Instead, I see the entire JSON response. How do I change this function so that It interprets the headers and status code as such, and not as content to render in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your API Gateway is using Lambda Proxy integration, just add `content-type: text/html` to your response.

Comment: Specifically, in the `headers` dictionary of your response

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way the lambda is configured with the lambda function. Looks like it is configured as a Lambda Proxy. If you want to see the entire JSON as the output, just disable the `Use Lambda Proxy integration`. You can find this configuration in the API Gateway console.

Enable the `Use Lambda Proxy integration` in the API Gateway console to see only the 'Hello, World!'

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use this function setting up the lambda proxy integration option from the API gateway. It will send you back only the body. You can set up quickly. Here is the official link. [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

Answer (score -1):

Lambda and API Gateway aren't supposed to be used as web servers returning HTML. They aren't even optimized for that, it would be waste of resources.

What you should do is have your HTML hosted somewhere else, use JavaScript to communicate with your API, get dynamic data, and then manipulate HTML based on the API responses.

In case you'd like a serverless approach for static HTML hosting, I recommend [S3 + CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/).

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question, which was why was API Gateway returning the entire JSON object to thr client instead of interpreting it to generate an HTTP response with the provided body, headers, and status code.  (This occurs if you neglect to use the Lambda proxy integration feature.)

Comment: Although you are right, I still consider worthwhile to provide a comprehensive view, instead of answering without any consideration to context and implications of a decision. There was already an answer for what you indicated, but it hadn't been accepted. I don't see any harm from posting a suggestion of alternative architecture and usage of a cloud resource, as I did...